# Landing Page on Amazon S3 with Form

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Ok so I'm very well aware that S3 is not a fileserver. That said, it's a great tool to manage static websites and many of my websites are 99% static for this project. I'm an AWS Solutions Architect and I still can't think of the easiest and most efficient way to process simple forms on an HTML page in S3.

Yes the obvious answer is spin up an EC2 instance with a PHP processing script, then I'll have to create an RDS instance, etc. which is a ton of work for simply pulling an email address from a site visitor. LAMBDA doesn't support PHP for some ungodly reason or else I'd write and run a function that way.

I've tried a dozen different ways to find a solution that scales but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API Gateway + Lambda for that.

After user enter static website (S3), provide some data in form and submit it - JavaScript can make request to API Gateway which will trigger Lambda.

For example - user can provide email address and Lambda can save that email in file on another S3 bucket or DynamoDB - depends on what you exacly want to do with that provided emails.

Comment: This certainly sounds interesting. They are just emails of people who are signing up for an app that hasn't launched yet so S3 would probably be fine for storing them until we're taken more than one input field in which case I'd use DynamoDB or RDS. Any tutorials or docs that speaks to your proposal in a bit more detail?